# Book Database Data

Tags: sql, database

I am creating a database which will contain information about book. (title, author, description, edition etc). Is there anyway i can download book data from the web so that i can insert in my database. I want database to have between 500 - 1000 books information. The database is in Sql Server.

Comment: I don't see how the database is germane to your data source problem.

Answer (score 1):

Most well known book content API's are from [Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/) and more recent from Google (Amazon's API can often seen been republished on the web):

**[Amazon Content API program](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html)**

**[Google Book Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/books/docs/gdata/developers_guide_protocol.html)**

To see what is allowed with the Amazon API please see:

**[Amazon Content API agreement](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/agreement.html)**

Some excelent info on other providers can be found here:
[Code4lib: Using Book Data Providers to Improve Services to Patrons](http://journal.code4lib.org/articles/1009)

Answer (score 0):

You could source data from websites like Amazon.com - they have APIs for this. But, you may not be able to redistribute the data without permission from Amazon. There's nothing stopping you from getting public domain data from a government organisation like the Library of Congress - they probably have it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for sample data you can use the pubs db that comes with ms sql server

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Archive offers [Open Library](http://openlibrary.org/) [bulk exports](http://www.archive.org/search.php?query=collection%3A%22ol_data%22) in a variety of formats (MARC, primarily). If you are looking for records for specific books, you might look at [LibraryThing's API](http://www.librarything.com/api).

Comment: how do you use the export, i mean how do you open the MARC or whatever extension the file is in ?

Comment: There are a bunch of tools developed within libraries to work with MARC: 
  - http://www.indexdata.com/blog/2009/10/z3950-dummies-part-4 
  - http://marc4j.tigris.org/
  - http://marc.rubyforge.org/
  - https://github.com/edsu/pymarc

Comment: i have a sql server database. Is it possible to import MARC file in sql database???